# Regular expression to match until last 3 characters before a comma

Tags: java, regex

Maybe this is asked somewhere but certainly I couldn't find the answer I want so:

I'm having difficulties to match specific characters in a string:

```
"88551554,86546546,51516565"
```

The digits I want to match are the X's in the following :

```
"XXXXX554,XXXXX546,XXXXX565"
```

Right now I'm only able to find out the last 3 digits before each comma :

```
\d{3}(?=,)
```

And since the length of the numbers are dynamic, it seems not possible to specify the number of digits before the 3 digits.

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this lookahead regex:

```
(\d+)(?=\d{3}(?:,|$))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dF1pY7/1)

This will match and group 1 or more digits that must be followed by 3 digits and a comma or end of input. Check **MATCH INFORMATION** in the demo link for captured groups.

---

**Update:** To replace all those matched digits by `X` use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d*\\d{3}(?:,|$))", "X");
```

#### RegEx Demo2

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does the job and matches. Actually I'm trying to replace the original string with those X's, so by finding the matches I'm only able to replace them by 1 "X". Any ideas? I know this is off topic anyway, but I'll appreciate if you can bring up suggestions :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot! just one more doubt, I noticed it's different from the regex you gave in the original answer, what does the "\d*" do before "\d{3}" exactly??

Comment: Yes little different because you want to replace all the digits with `X`. It matches individual digits that are followed by this pattern: `(?=\\d*\\d{3}(?:,|$))`

Comment: Got it! so the "\d*" specifies the individual characters right?

Comment: Yes and the site you provided is so powerful! thanks again and have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

To match it use:

```
\d+(?=\d{3})
```

This regex does:

`\d+`... Match a digit (0-9) between one and unlimmited times.
 `(?=\d{3})` ... Match a digit (0-9) exactly three times inside an positive lookahead.